# How to use Execute Immedite with CTE in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run below query to insert data to some table using CTE in Oracle stored procedure. But it seems that we cannot use INTO clause with Execute Immediate statement.

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE_MAIN
(
COL1,
COL2,
COL3
)
WITH CTE_TEST_TABLE_DATE AS (
SELECT 
a.COL1,
a.COL2,
a.COL3
FROM TEST_TABLE_2 a LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT GROUP_ID FROM TEST_REF_TABLE) b
 on a.COL1= b.GROUP_ID
)
SELECT * FOM CTE_TEST_TABLE_DATE';
END;
```

I am creating TEST_TABLE_2 using some other table and that's the reason why I am using Dynamic sql. I am not getting how to fix this issue.

It's giving me below error while trying to execute the procedure.
ORA-00905 missing keyword

Edit- I have just noticed that there's a case statement in one of the CTE which is causing the issue. If I comment out this CTE then it's working fine.
else it's giving me an error like

pls-00103 encountered the symbol

```
,CTE_Age_Band AS(
select a.*,
CASE WHEN ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") = NULL then ''
     WHEN ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") < 1 then 'Less than one year'
     WHEN ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL")  >=1 and ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL")  <=17 then '1 - 17 years'
     ELSE 'More than 17 years'
END as "AGE_BAND"
from CTE_XYZ a
)
select * from CTE_Age_Band';
END;
/
```

Comment: Did you try to run the insert statement without the PL/SQL? Can you post the full error stack?

Comment: Yeah. Then it gives me an error like object does not exists.. I am creating test_table_2 in the same procedure only

Comment: What is your Business Requirement?  to me, it feels like you are trying to implement some sort of SQL Server "best practice" (which happens to be an Oracle "Worst Practice")

Comment: Michael Kutz.. yeah exactly.. I will post my query tommrow. Thanks for understanding my problem

Comment: Please post complete code not just problematic lines ,from which table are you referring to member_age_final?

Comment: @Sam.. I will post it today. Thanks

Comment: I have posted another question with a complete code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789876/facing-strange-issue-while-executing-oracle-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

More likely a syntax error in your SQL statement.

Inserting in dynamic SQL using a CTE works fine.

```
SQL> create table t1 (c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> begin  execute immediate'
  2  insert into t1(c1)
  3  with g as (select rownum from dual connect by level<=3)
  4  select * from g';
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from t1;

        C1
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

Comment: Yeah.. I have added the problematic part of the query. Sorry for reformatting my laptop doesn't have Chrome to edit it properly.. I  am struggling to address this issue